# Alternative to setInterval that waits for function to complete

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently, I'm using setInterval to run several AJAX functions that call PHP pages like so -

```
var intervalOne = setInterval(ajaxfunction, 1500);
```

This works fine on a test server with a tiny response time. However occasionally on my live server, there will be a bit of lag and the interval time will come again before the first one has finished, repeating the same call, and causing duplicate data to appear.

Is there any way to keep the same interval time, but have it wait to call the function if the first one hasn't finished yet?

Alternatively, Is there anything I can put in a readystate portion of the AJAX calls to have them trigger themselves again once they are complete?

Edit - Example of one of my ajax calls:

```
function Send() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var message = document.getElementById('message').value;

var xmlhttp = getXMLHttp();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById('message').value = "";

        if(xmlhttp.responseText != "") {
            var chat = document.getElementById('messagebox');
            chat.innerHTML = chat.innerHTML + '<div class=\"alert\">' + xmlhttp.responseText + '</div>';
            chat.scrollTop = 1000000000;
        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","submit_message.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name=" + name + "&message=" + message);

}
```

Comment: Just call setTimeout at the end of the function instead?

Comment: show your AJAX calls so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: @James can I really call a function inside of itself?

Comment: @Morgan: You can call a function from inside itself, it's called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). However, here you're not calling a function from inside itself, you're *scheduling* a function from inside itself - which is somewhat different (and yes, also possible). In fact, scheduling a function is simpler, since you don't get run out of stack (a common danger with true recursion, especially in languages without [tail-call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimisation). For added fun: see "Did you mean..." in [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=recursion).

Comment: SetInterval is very helpful. I was aware of recursion but I thought most languages didn't allow it to take place.

Comment: Most languages _do_ allow recursion - certainly 100% of the languages I'd care to work with do. But normally recursion is used such that a condition in the function stops it going too many levels deep, e.g., if you recursively parse a tree data structure eventually you'll hit the bottom of the tree and start coming back up... (And as Amadan explained, you don't want recursion here anyway: using `setTimeout` within a function schedules a later call to itself which isn't recursion.)

Comment: I was just always taught that recursion was "dangerous" and to avoid it. It's not come up often enough until now that I would have questioned it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easy way is through blindly reapplying `setTimeout` at the end of your process:

```
function foo() {
  // possibly long task
  setTimeout(foo, 1500);
}
foo();
```

This would wait 1500ms between your processes. Like this: 300ms process, 1500ms wait, 2000ms process, 1500ms wait, 400ms process, 1500ms wait...

A bit more closely to what you want, you could reapply `setTimeout` at the *beginning* of your process. In this case, you'd get: 300ms process, 1200ms wait, 2000ms process, 0ms wait, 400ms process, 1100ms wait... The problem that happens with `setInterval` doesn't happen here, because this only schedules the *next* iteration, not all future ones. Notice also that since JS is single-threaded, an event can't interrupt itself like you could get in some other languages.

```
function foo() {
  setTimeout(foo, 1500);
  // possibly long task
}
foo();
```

And yeah, I guess it's more popular these days to make it self-executing, as you can see in some answers; but that's just aesthetics, the end effect is the same.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need. I didn't realize I could set parameters to affect the iteration of a function inside of the function's own declaration.

Comment: morgan always make another ajax request when one is completed,therfore try @TomaszNurkiewicz's answer

Answer (score 5):

You can replace `setInterval()` with `setTimeout()` being constantly rescheduled on every AJAX response:

```
function Send() {
    //...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            setTimeout(Send, 1500);
            //...
        }
    }
}

Send();
```

If you don't need millisecond precision this is fine (time between calls will be 1500 ms + average response time). If you need to call the server exactly every 1500 milliseconds you can subtract response time from 1500 ms.

Comment: best answer but it is not tagged under jquery

Comment: It is a helpful answer, but I prefer not to add jquery for one single task. :)

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble: [tag:jquery] was used only to highlight the idea, but since OP posted the original code, using raw XMLHttpRequest instead.

Comment: @Morgan: sorry, [tag:jquery] was really relevant there, here is a version using plain AJAX.

Comment: @Tomasz Didn't mean to complain, was just pointing it out. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a self invoking function along with `setTimeout` like this:

```
(function foo(){

 // your code logic here

 setTimeout(foo, 5000);

})();
```

The difference here is that it would work similar to `setInterval` but unlike it, the next call to function will be run only after `your code logic here` part has finished executing.

See the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/usali4)** here.